(Old?) Animated Bunny movie that starts with mean bunnies chasing the good bunny
I'm looking for a movie that I don't remember much of. It was aninated and I think old. I probably watched it in 2010 or some time around that. But I don't know when it came out.
All I remember is, the movie started with this group of bunnies chasing this other bunny and they catch him behind a tree and force him to be in their bunny group thing (for what reason I don't know). And the ones that chased the bunny are, I guess, the bad guys.
Also later on in another scene the bunny that got chased and this girl bunny (I think) that knew each other attempted to escape the evil bunnies. I don't remember if they got away or not. I'm also not sure if the movie was centered around those two bunnies.
I think the movie kept switching from those two to someone else. I believe the bunny that got chased was brown (maybe dark brown) and the girl bunny was a bit lighter. I was little so I don't remember much. Please don't suggest it to be Watership Down. It's not. 

Do the bunnies look like real bunnies, a la Watership Down, or are they humanoid bunnies, a la Bugs Bunny?

They looked like real bunnies
